# Is there a way or a tool to see the html a view would generate before it is rendered into the dom in Ember?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a view which I need to render into a boostrap popup. However, it is not rendering when I say `Em.Handlebars.compile('{{view App.MyView}}')` and pass it to the `message` property of the bootstrap Modal pane. I want to know if there is a way to generate the html which the view will emit when inserted into the dom and use that html as a string and pass it to the modal pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple use cases this will work

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('hello {{title}}');
var context = {title: "My New Post"};
var html    = template(context);
```

For more advanced cases, which you're referring to, you should do something like this

```
var view = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: 'say-hello',
  name: "Bob"
});

view.appendTo('#container');
```

or

```
var view = App.MyView.create();
```

You also may want to look at https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember and https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap